# SSIS variable Excel sheet name error with and without dollar sign $

Tags: excel, for-loop, ssis

I am in a catch 22 situation trying to code a for each loop to dynamically create a list of Excel files. In the for each loop I have an execute SQL task that runs a create table statement with the name of the sheet/tab. This precedes a data flow task that runs a query based on a parm set in the loop and attempts to write the results to Excel. The problem is either in the Excel destination object or the SQL task that creates the table.

The name of the sheet is set via a variable. In all the examples online you do NOT include the dollar sign ($) in the sheet name, like "report". However when I do this the Excel destination cannot find the sheet/tab which means I cannot edit the object to map/remap columns. But, when I change the variable to include the dollar sign like "report$", the Excel destination object works but then when running the package the create table step throws an error saying "opening a rowset for 'report' failed. Check that the object exists in the database".

Any ideas?

```html
"CREATE TABLE `" +  @[User::excel_tab_name] + "` (
```

Comment: Have you tried to troubleshoot by using two separate variables for the table name and sheet name, one without the $ and the other with?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something but I consider table and sheet names to be the same thing. The code says "table" but we are creating a "sheet" in Excel. I have not tried 2 different variables but I have tried adding the $ and then removing it. As indicated, when I make this change it causes an error in one place while fixing the other.